# SASS: Using @forward and @use, then configuring preprocessorOptions in vite.config.js

Tags: javascript, sass, vite

I don't quite understand how to use the scss syntax - `@use` and `@forward`.
I have a few problems with this:

Problem 1. I have two folders: 1) `src/assets/scss/base` and `src/assets/scss/util`, in each of these folders there is a corresponding scss file, for example, `_variables.scss` or `_container.scss`. Then, I create `_index.scss` in each of these two folders and add there `@forward 'variables'` and `@forward 'container'`. Then, in `src/assets/scss/main.scss` I use `@use 'base' as *;` and `@use 'util' as *;`. However, I get an error that one of the variables is not found, as if these instructions don't work. Where is the mistake?

Problem 2: I also use Vite, and when I used `@import` instead of `@use` and `@forward` before, I had to include all scss files in preprocessorOptions in `vite.config.js`. But now that I'm using `@use` and `@forward`, do I add these options correctly?

```
export default defineConfig({
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `@use '@/assets/scss/main' as *;`,
            },
        },
    },
});
```